# BEM. Can Elements contain Blocks?

Tags: html, css, bem

#### Here is my HTML

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="menu__item">
    <a href="" class="menu__link"></a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu__item">
    <ul class="list"> // can I place this block inside here?
      <li class="list__item">
        ...
      </li>
      <li class="list__item">
        ...
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In this case, I place the block `list` inside the element `menu__item`.

I wonder, is this legal?

Comment: If you want this naming scheem for `ul class="list"`, then the list should be a standalone component that can be used in many places without the parent wrappers.

Comment: I think it is OK to use block inside block as long as your parent block doesn't have any say on styles inside the child block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per this documentation from BEM, we can nest the blocks. I.e. a block can have another block in it. 
The only condition is that the children blocks should be independent on the parent.

https://en.bem.info/methodology/block-modification/#placing-a-block-inside-another-block

Comment: Thanks, I think I get it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is valid. See example from section `Nested Lists`
 in - https://html.com/lists/.

Comment: But this is BEM methodology I'm talking about.